# Python RAW socket interpret data bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I want to build a packet sniffer in python that is able to sniff packets, analyze them and in a second step inject packets on a local interface.

I have found an example that I had to tweak a bit to work. My working version looks like this:

```
from pprint import pprint
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.bind(("192.168.1.100", 0))
#s.socketopt(socket.IPPOROT_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
#s.ioct(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
i = 5
while i > 0:
    data = s.recvfrom(10000)
    pprint(data)
    i -= 1
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
(b'E\x00\x008\x05>\x00\x00@\x06\xf1c\xc0\xa8\x01j\xc0\xa8\x01d\x10\x00#*'
 b'\xe25\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x11\x1c\x8cQ\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\xb4'
 b'\x08\n\x00Q,\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 ('192.168.1.106', 0))
(b'E\x00\x008\x05?\x00\x00@\x06\xf1b\xc0\xa8\x01j\xc0\xa8\x01d\x10\x01#*'
 b'\xd0\x03\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x11\x1c\x00o\x00\x00'
 b'\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x08\n\x00Q,\xe6\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 ('192.168.1.106', 0))
(b'E\x00\x008\x05@\x00\x00@\x06\xf1a\xc0\xa8\x01j\xc0\xa8\x01d\x10\x02#*'
 b'\xa5\xd18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x11\x1c\x8c\x8c\x00\x00'
 b'\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x08\n\x00Q,\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 ('192.168.1.106', 0))
(b'E\x00\x008\x05A\x00\x00@\x06\xf1`\xc0\xa8\x01j\xc0\xa8\x01d\x10\x03#*'
 b'\x96\x9e\xd6\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x11\x1c\xfd\xa9\x00\x00'
 b'\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x08\n\x00Q-\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 ('192.168.1.106', 0))
(b'E\x00\x008\x05B\x00\x00@\x06\xf1_\xc0\xa8\x01j\xc0\xa8\x01d\x10\x04#*'
 b'\xa9\xb0\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x11\x1c\xc2\x82\x00\x00'
 b'\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x08\n\x00Q-"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 ('192.168.1.106', 0))
```

The output confused me quite a bit and I am not sure how to use it. I expected a byte array but in the multiple arrays there are several characters that I do not expect there, like E, >, @, #, and so on. I tried to find out what they mean but I was not able to get any information that explains how it is to be used. I want to parse information from the TCP part and analyze them but I cannot make any progress on this.

If someone could explain to me what exactly the format of the byte array is and what each of the components mean that would be very helpful!

Many thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: I'm interpreting this as "It's surprising to me that my data contains E, >, etc. I would expect my data to be homogeneous, containing only `\x` values". An `E` inside a byte array isn't qualitatively different from a value that starts with `\x`. It just so happens that the value in one slot has a printable character representation, and the value in other slot doesn't. You may be better off thinking of bytes as lists of small integers. `b"E\x00"` is effectively the same as `[69, 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin's comment helped me in solving my problem:

This is the code that works for me. It does not feel like a clean solution but it works. If someone knows a proper way how to print the actual bytes without converting them, I would appreciate knowing that as well.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.bind(("192.168.1.100", 0))

i = 5
while i > 0:
    data = s.recvfrom(10000)
    print("b'{}'".format(''.join(' {:02x}'.format(b) for b in data[0])))
    i -= 1
```

Comment: finally what did you do ?

Answer (score 0):

your output shows byte streams, they looks like **b'x'**. in sender side a data **encode(data)** with a encoding type (e.g: **'ascii'** or **'utf-8'** or ...) and receiver **decode(data)** in other side. so you should realize correct encoding type and decode(data) in your side. Respect

Comment: Unfortunately, decoding did not help.